On two "versions" of abc conjecture
Let $a,b,c$ be coprime nonzero positive integers such that $a+b=c$. The ABC conjecture states that for any $\varepsilon>0$, we have $$c < C_{\varepsilon}\operatorname{rad}(abc)^{1+\varepsilon}.$$
There is also another weaker version of the ABC conjecture, which states that for any $\varepsilon>0$, we have $$abc < C_{\varepsilon}\operatorname{rad}(abc)^{3(1+\varepsilon)}.$$
I am wondering: is it known that the second inequality implies the first one?

Is there a family of such conjectures for any each positive real constant $q$ in front of $(1+\epsilon)$?

@GHfromMO, re, right, I don't know what I was thinking.  I have deleted my very wrong comment.

I doubt that this implication is known. If $a$ and $b$ are of roughly the same size, then $c\approx(abc)^{1/3}$, and you'll get the desired implication. But if, say, $a$ is small compared to $b$, then all that you get (for free) is
$$ \text{rad}(abc)^{3+\epsilon} \ge C_\epsilon abc \approx C_\epsilon c^2, $$
which yields $c\le\text{rad}(abc)^{3/2+\epsilon}$. So "weak $abc$" seems to imply "other weak $abc$ with exponent $3/2$", but not all the way down to exponent $1$.
